# Embedded Ruby not being interpolated

Tags: view, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

Not sure why this line is not working

CONTROLLER

```
@images = {
    "Example1" => "ExampleA",
    "Example2" => "ExampleB",
}
```

VIEW

```
<% @images.each do |image, caption| %>
    <div class ="fill" style="background-image: url(<%= asset_path '#{image}.jpg' %>);">
        <div class="caption">
            <h2><%= "#{caption}" %></h2>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

When I look at the output, somehow the HTML being rendered for the background image is:

```
<div class="fill" style="background-image: url(/#{image}.jpg);">
```

As general practice, my understanding is that the interpolation tags, either <% or <%=, should be as close to the Ruby code as possible (e.g, within HTML tags, or in the example of the background-image: url above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interpolation works with double quotes, not single quotes.

Change

`style="background-image: url(<%= asset_path '#{image}.jpg' %>);"`

To

`style='background-image: url(<%= asset_path "#{image}.jpg" %>);'`

or

`style="background-image: url(<%= asset_path image %>.jpg);"`